# How do I get the width of sub menu items to auto resize

Tags: html, css

When I set the width of the sub menu to **width:auto**, the items with really long names gets squished together. Currently I have the width set to 175% which is not desirable as some menus can get quiet long. How can I make width:auto work for long menu items.

Link to demo site: http://previewyournewwebsite.info/otsl/

[image]

```
.nav.main_nav .sub-menu {
    background-color: #2D556F;
    display: none;
    height: auto;
    /* left: -5px; */
    left: 0px;
    margin: 0 9px 0 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 54px;
    width: 175%;
}

.nav.main_nav .sub-menu li {
    margin: 30px 0px;
    display: block;
}


.nav.main_nav .sub-menu li a {
    background-image: url("./images/sub-nav-divider.png");
    background-position: 0 bottom;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-left: -31px;
    padding: 0 0 0 44px;
    width: 100%;
}

.nav.main_nav .sub-menu > li{
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    padding-left: 44px;
}

.nav.main_nav .sub-menu > li:last-child a{
    background-image: none;
}

.nav.main_nav .sub-menu li {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
}
```

**Link to site:** http://previewyournewwebsite.info/otsl/

Comment: Did you find my answer useful?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

http://jsfiddle.net/coma/MNFXB/11/

```
nav ul, nav li {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

nav a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 1em;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #2D556F;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

nav > ul {
    background-color: #2D556F;
}

nav > ul:after {
    display: block;
    content: "";
    clear: both;
}

nav > ul > li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

nav > ul > li > ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    display: none;
}

nav > ul > li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}

nav li:hover > a {
    background-color: #92A132;
}
```

Or would you like something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/coma/MNFXB/12/

Comment: something like the first one

Comment: What do i have to change to get it?

Comment: I wasn't sure if you wanted to avoid the line break as the first one. The only difference is the nowrap.

Comment: There is no need of setting width neither height, just play with float, clear that float and use relative > absolute to get the subs into the right position.